# Cannot get NBD to work

Tags: nbd

According to [this blog post](https://medium.com/@aysadx/linux-nbd-introduction-to-linux-network-block-devices-143365f1901b), it should be easy:

```
# nbd-server MyFile.dat
# nbd-client localhost /dev/nbd0
```

Trouble is... that doesn't actually *work*.

First of all, `nbd-server` whinges and whines about "no configured exports", unless I explicitly specify a port number and the absolute path to the file. But OK, whatever. (It *still* complains that this is "deprecated" somehow and that you should really edit the config file instead — which I *definitely* don't want to do!) It appears to now be serving the block device. (At least, there's now an `nbd-server` process running, which has TCP/10809 open for listening.)

Trying to get `nbd-client` to connect, however, is impossible. No matter what arguments I give it, it moans and complains and refuses to *do* anything! It keeps saying

```
 ERROR: not enough information specified
```

followed by the usage synopsis. But it won't actually *tell me* what it's unhappy about. Either with or without a port number specified, I get the same error message. How do I make it *actually connect?*

(Obviously I'm connecting to the same machine. Eventually I want to do this between machines on the network. But I can't even get it to work locally yet!)

PS. Some examples talk about `modprobe nbd-client` and `modprobe nbd-server`. My OpenSUSE machine appears to only have `nbd.ko`, so I've inserted that. Before that, `/dev/nbd0` doesn't even exist. After that, it exists just fine.

Comment: @cas Does it matter which blog post? Either the commands are correct or they aren't. As I explained, `nbd-server MyData.dat` doesn't work, whereas `nbd-server 10809 /home/fred/MyData.dat` appears to work. I can't get `nbd-client` to work at all; `nbd-client localhost /dev/nbd0` doesn't work. `nbd-client localhost 10809 /dev/nbd0` doesn't work. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: @cas OK. Just for you, I edited in a link to the blog post.

Comment: It's not just for cas. They have a valid point that we need information to be able to evaluate the situation appropriately

Comment: The blog post looks a bit lightweight and vague, but there are no obvious errors.  Is your ndb server listening on your loopback interface (i.e. localhost, 127.0.0.1) or only on your NIC's interface?  (the ndb-server man page says it listens on all interfaces by default, but man pages aren't always accurate).  Try specifying the host and port explicitly.  e.g. `nbd-server localhost:10809 MyFile.dat`   and `nbd-client localhost 10809 /dev/ndb0`.

Comment: The blog is out of date. I'm looking for something newer before writing an answer for you. https://github.com/NetworkBlockDevice/nbd looks plausible

Comment: @cas `lsof` indicates the server is listening on `TCP *:10809`, which I *think* means all interfaces. Regardless, I tried setting it explicitly (`lsof` now says `TCP localhost:10809`). It doesn't seem to make any difference to `nbd-client`. It still says "not enough information specified", whatever that means.

Comment: I spent some time experimenting with nbd-server and nbd-client yesterday, and I think the only way you're going to get this working is to use a config file - at the very least, an authorisation file to list IP addresses allowed to connect).   You can use `-C` to specify your own config file instead of the default (dunno what distro you're using, but on debian the default is `/etc/nbd-server/config`).   Also, I don't know what your distro does, but debian runs nbd-server itself as user `nbd` so you'll need to be careful about ownership and permissions of files.

Comment: also, avoid making the same mistake I made repeatedly, mistyping `nbd` as `ndb` - this is especially annoying when you mistype the device name as `/dev/ndb0`.

Comment: If these comments help you figure it out, please write it up as an answer to help the next person with a similar question.  You can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took some figuring out.

It seems that as well as the NBD server and port number, you also need to specify an "export name", which the documentation doesn't really explain very well.

I also had to resort to using a config file [which I desparately wanted to avoid]. Fortunately, you don't actually have to put it in any special location or anything.

I was able to actually get the following to work:

1. Create an empty disk image.
2. Create a file looking something like this:

   ```
   [generic]
   # Must always exist.

   [Mu]
   exportname=/path/to/image/file
   ```
3. Start the NBD server:

   ```
   nbd-server -C /path/to/config/file
   ```

   This seems to generate `/var/run/nbd-server.pid`, which holds the PID of the NBD server process (i.e., so you can kill it). There doesn't seem to be any other stop command.
4. Start the NBD client:

   ```
   nbd-client localhost -N Mu /dev/nbd0
   ```

   The `Mu` part has to match whatever random name you chose in the config file. It's perfectly possible for a single server to serve *multiple* files as once, so you need to specify which one you want. (This is presumably the “not enough information” that the client was whining about before.)

At this point, `/dev/nbd0` should function as a normal block device.

So far, I haven't found any way to disconnect, other than killing the client/server processes (e.g., `pkill nbd`).

I have also tested; this works remotely, if you replace `localhost` with the appropriate hostname.

Comment: To disconnect use `nbd-client -d /dev/nbd0`.  To check if connected use `nbd-client -c /dev/nbd0`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [nbdkit](https://gitlab.com/nbdkit/nbdkit) instead of nbd-server.  (Note: I wrote it).  It's a more modern and capable server, and by default it doesn't care about export names.  Here's an example of using it to create a 1 terabyte RAM disk, and connecting to that using nbd-client:

```
$ nbdkit memory 1T
$ sudo nbd-client localhost /dev/nbd0
Negotiation: ..size = 1048576MB
Connected /dev/nbd0
$ sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/nbd0
1099511627776
```

Another tool that we wrote is [nbdinfo](https://gitlab.com/nbdkit/libnbd) which can be used to query NBD servers for their properties, including listing export names that they serve:

```
$ nbdinfo nbd://localhost
protocol: newstyle-fixed without TLS
export="":
    export-size: 1099511627776
    content: data
    uri: nbd://localhost:10809/
[more output clipped]
```

To clean up:

```
$ sudo nbd-client -d /dev/nbd0
$ killall nbdkit
```

(If you were doing this properly there are better ways than `killall`.  You could have nbdkit write a PID file and then kill that PID.  Or you could use [captive nbdkit](https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/new-in-nbdkit-run-nbdkit-as-a-captive-process/))